# Send parts of a byte[] by webclient to create a large file in server side

Tags: c#, silverlight, arrays, webclient

So trying to Transfer a large byte[] for that chose to separate it in chunks of 20MB, and in the first chunk received create the file and add that,the rest open the existing file and add the remaining.The problem that I am having is instead of send the first part and reconnect to receive the second part its establishing the two connections and sending the two chunks at the same time.. how can send the second after the first as finished?

```
client.OpenWriteAsync(ub.Uri); 

void client_OpenWriteCompleted(object sender, OpenWriteCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Cancelled)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Cancelled");
    }
    else if (e.Error != null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Deu erro");
    }
    else
    {
        try
        {
            using (Stream output = e.Result)
            {
                int countbytes;

                //for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
                //{
                if ( (max+1) != maxAux)
                {
                    countbytes = zippedMemoryStream.Read(PartOfDataSet, 0 , 20000000);//maxAux * 20000000
                    output.Write(PartOfDataSet, 0, (int)countbytes);
                    if (max != maxAux)
                    {

                       client.OpenWriteAsync(ub.Uri); 

                    }
                    maxAux++;

                }

                //}

                //numeroimagem++;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            //throw;
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    //context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
    //context.Response.Write("Hello World");

    string ImageName = context.Request.QueryString["ImageName"];
    string UploadPath = context.Server.MapPath("~/ServerImages/");

    byte[] bytes = new byte[20000000];
    int bytesToRead = 0;

    if (!File.Exists(UploadPath + ImageName))
    {
        using (FileStream stream = File.Create(UploadPath + ImageName))
        {

            try
            {
                //List<byte> bytes = new List<byte>();


                while ((bytesToRead =
                context.Request.InputStream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) != 0)
                //context.Request.InputStream.Read(bytes, 0, 200000)) != 0)
                {

                    stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytesToRead);
                    stream.Close();

                }

                bytes = null;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string error = ex.Message;
                throw;
            }

        }
    }
    else
    {
        using (FileStream stream = File.Open(UploadPath + ImageName,FileMode.Append))
        {

            try
            {

                while ((bytesToRead =
                context.Request.InputStream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) != 0)
                {

                    stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytesToRead);
                    stream.Close();

                }
                bytes = null;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string error = ex.Message;
                throw;
            }

        }
    }

}

public bool IsReusable
{
    get
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact you gain nothing by opening the client again. You can just loop over your zippedMemoryStream in chunks and write it to the output stream. Then the data will arrive in order on the server side.

Otherwise look into the UploadData methods, if you really want to create a new connection each time.

Comment: but when I call the second time `client.OpenWriteAsync(ub.Uri);` that is the one inside `client_OpenWriteCompleted` it was suppose to have sent the `output.Write(PartOfDataSet, 0, (int)countbytes);` first before calling the connection second time.

Comment: In fact you gain nothing by opening the client again.  You can just loop over your zippedMemoryStream in chunks and write it to the output stream.  Then the data will arrive in order on the server side.

Comment: Otherwise look into the UploadData methods, if you really want to create a new connection each time.

Comment: yes you maybe in the right direction there thanks, will try that, in sending in one connection only.